# How much more expensive is the creation of an object without data in Java instead of the use of static methods?

Tags: java, interface, static-methods

Java lacks the ability to specify interfaces for static methods. A method in an interface must be non static. This makes it impossible to specify requirements for Classes. Instead one is limited to specify requirements for Objects. This makes it also impossible for example to specify the singleton functionality in an interface, because in Java the singleton pattern requires to be implemented as a static method. [Here](http://www.theserverside.de/singleton-pattern-in-java/) is a nice article, which explains it, but it is only in German.

When one is forced to implement something as a functionality of an object instead of the functionality of a class, an instance of this object has to be created, before the functionality can be used. But such object has some special characteristic: it has no state, because class functionality has no state either. Theoretically the instance creation of an object without data can be optimized to an [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP), because all methods can be linked to the class instead of any object. Java could implement some kind of implicit singleton functionality.

But how it this actually handled?

Think about some kind of functionality without any state.

```
interface Adder<T> { T add(T ... arguments); }
```

Basically it would be sufficient to implement this as a static method:

```
class IntegerAdder implements Adder<Integer> {
   public static Integer add (Integer ... arguments) { }
}
```

But because Java does not allow static interface methods it has to be implemented in a non static way. The result is, that when ever an `IntegerAdder` is required one has to create an instance.

```
IntegerAdder integer_adder = new IntegerAdder();
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 2;
Integer c = integer_adder.add (1, 2);
```

I fear this might be slower than the version without the instance creation:

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 2;
Integer c = IntegerAdder.add (1, 2);
```

But how much slower is it in reality? Is it possible for the Java compiler to optimize the first version in that way that it performs as fast as the second one? And is this actually done?

Comment: That depends on the currency you operate. CPU, Memory, Work hours ?

Comment: Is this theoretical or practical, if its practical then profile, I'd be suprised if it makes a significant difference unless you're initialising hundreds of thousands of them

Comment: @Vash Work hours is obvious: one line of code for each operation. I had CPU time in mind.

Comment: Creating an object in Java is one of the cheapest things to do unless you do not do anything in the c'tor like copy an array or something ike that.

Comment: @RichardTingle I asked because I thought someone did this already. I did not expect that I am the first who thought about the limitations of interfaces in Java.

Comment: @ceving Yes, but the trouble is that it depends so much on your specific circumstances, will it take some time; probably, will that time be important; almost certainly not, but it could be if you do it a gadzillion times

Comment: @RichardTingle My specific problem is a typical driver. I have an interface which describes the driver operations and some classes which implement the interface in several individual ways. And because of the fact that it is a driver it contains low level operations, where performance is likely be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of IntegerAdder once and reuse it, it is thread safe. Also pay attention that `Integer ... arguments` leads to 1) using objects instead of primitive ints 2) creating an array to pass parameters. Both things should be avoided if performance is concern

Comment: You mean my example is not well suited, because the limitation of Java´s implementation of variable arguments lists is much worse than the limitation of interfaces?

Comment: I mean if you make it static it will not significantly improve performance because calling add(Integer ... arguments) will need to create an array, Integer objects, filling arguments with objects